# 'TF Dynamics CRM Destination' showing error message: "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes"

Tags: ssis, guid

I am a newbie in this field, so perhaps I am just completely missing something obvious here, but I'm running into an error with my SSIS package that I can't solve. I have an OLDB Source and a Task Factory Dynamics destination. I am continuously getting the following error:

> [TF Dynamics CRM Destination [74]] Error: An error occurred with the following error message: "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes (xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxxxxxxxxxx).".

I have scoured the internet and see a lot of people have this error, but it is almost always associated with C# or VB or HTML or some other language with which I am unfamiliar. I've tried altering some of those solutions the best I can to solve the issue, but no luck so far. I have also seen from my search that this error frequently occurs in Management Studio with Maintenance plans, but I don't think that helps me solve my issue. I can't find very much on this error associated with SSIS.

Comment: Can you post a liitle more info about your data flow? What kind of information are you outputting to your destination? And I think this goes without saying, but have you checked that your `guid` column has "32 digits with 4 dashes"?

Comment: Output to destination are things like product name, product group, description, created by, etc. Types: mostly varchars, a few int and date types. I actually don't even have a guid column. I tried adding a guid column via a SQL command in my source, thinking that may help, but it doesn't seem to make any difference...getting the same error.

Comment: I found [this](http://help.pragmaticworks.com/taskfactory/index.htm) The 'CRM Destination' is about half way down. The only thing I can think of is one of your destination columns being configured to be a guid. Your server can also expect a guid for each record.